# Confusion in generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics in java.At first we made a arraylist of Integer and we added a value in list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericsRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
    }

    static <X extends List> void duplicate(X list) {
        list.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

The Method duplicate can be only used by those objects which are extending `List`. But, since `List` is interface

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

And `ArrayList` is implemeting `List`

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable,    
                   java.io.Serializable
```

I got stuck at this point. Extends is used by those classes which inherits the property from super class.
But how `Arraylist` is extending `List`? Actually `ArrayList` is implementing `List`. How is this extends keyword working for this implements mechanism? I am getting confused that it is using `extends` and `implements` are same?

Comment: Did you notice that it's **`extends AbstractList`** and not `extends List`?

Comment: yes but it is also implementing the List?

Comment: Yes, that may just make redundant declarations, but `AbstractList` is already implementing `List`, so `List<E>` could in a sense be removed from the `implements` interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `<X extends T>` means just that `X` is inherited from `T`. There is no special syntax for interfaces like when you describe inheritance in class declaration.

`ArrayList` implements interface `List` which means that it is inherited from `List`, thus it is suitable for generic type `<X extends List>`.

In Java any class can extend *only one* class. By default it's `Object` when you do not specify another parent class. And class and interface can implement any amount of interfaces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if a class is implenting interface than can we say that , it is being inherited?